# Codeigniter UPS API Integration - Delivery Dates

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, ups

I am using codeigniter framework and I have integrated UPS rates into my site.  Recently I wanted to add the expected delivery date but I noticed that the UPS API is returning Delivery Dates for everything *except* UPS Ground (code 03).

I can't figure out what I'm missing or doing wrong but I know other sites give estimates for UPS Ground shipping

I am using this UPS Library: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/UPS_Rate_Tool/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted UPS directly to get the answer to this.  It turns out they only give Delivery Dates for Guaranteed services and UPS Ground is not guaranteed therefore when you request a rate there will be no data for the Delivery Date.

Since UPS Ground is not guaranteed you can only get an estimated ship date which must be done using a separate ups api: 'Time in Transit API'
Xpath – /TimeInTransitResponse/TransitResponse/ServiceSummary/EstimatedArrival/Arrival/Date

Hope this saves someone the time and confusion that I had!

Comment: hey - the api link seems broken, can you help me getting the api code?!

Comment: I looks like Ellislab messed something up when transferring everything over to GitHub: [GitHub Holding Page](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/UPS-Rate-Tool) There should be some other UPS library out there that you can setup quick